# I see a link to dismiss a flag when I don't have the privileges to do so

Tags: bug, status-completed

I see a "dismiss" link beside a flag, but I don't have the privileges to dismiss flags. When I click on it, I get the yellow pop-up shown in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: +1, I see the same thing.

Comment: Maybe you've won the election in such a landslide that you've been given privileges early? :)

Comment: Happens on Stack Overflow as well. Might be worth reporting on MSO.

Comment: @ChrisF we've seen it; will fix

Comment: @Marc - can you let us know when it's fixed so I can mark this as `[status-completed]`

Comment: @ChrisF will do... just this small thing called "weekend" that slows me down...

Comment: This will be fixed next build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should now be fixed. (And no, I don't mean because you were elected a moderator..)

Comment: If all meta backends are linked, this is not yet fixed: as a 10k user I still see 'dismiss' links for flagged comments (but not flagged questions).